# Is it possible to add ads in Flask Web Application?

Tags: python, flask, ads

I want to develop a Web application with Python (deployed in Heroku). I have considered to use Flask. I would like to monetize the website with ads (Google Ads or similar).

Is it possible?
I have seen that Djando has "django-ads 1.1.1" (Ads Management System for Django Framework). Exists something similar in Flask?

Comment: You can simply add your JS code for advertisement in your `base.html` or each html page in your templates folder

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would change, just put the advertisement code for Google Ads in HTML and JS and it'll work